# MVC model null object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model

I am having a problem when posting through a method. I am first calling the view and passing the model through the view. But when the model is then return and posted all the model will be null. here is my code below

this method returns the model succesfully and all items needed

```
public ActionResult RenewFixed(int id)
    { 
        return View(new TransferModel(id, new Service1Client().getIdbyUsername(User.Identity.Name)));
    }
```

here the model reset all the items to null and an error occured

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RenewFixed(int id, TransferModel model)
    {
        model.myAccount.FixedDate = DateTime.Today;
        model.myAccount.RateId = model.monthFixed;
        new Service1Client().updateAccount(model.myAccount);
        return View("Index");
    }
```

Comment: can you check your `ModelState`?

Comment: Can you post your model definition please i.e. your TransferModel class?

Comment: also can you post what your form looks like?

Comment: You're most likely leaving all the data from the model in the view.  You have to wrap whatever you need returned to the server in form elements or hidden fields.  Can you post the code for the form (from the view?)

Answer (score -1):

Try using `FormCollection`. Or if you wanted to use model then make the id as property in your Model class, which will be hidden in your View. something like :

```
@Html.HiddenFor("ID")
```

then you can access Id with model such as model.ID

Comment: `FormCollection` really goes against the way of MVC.

Comment: but still you can use FormCollection in this scenario. and you didn't read my full answer